# Report error in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this function that convert a number into a certain base.I want to report an error if the base I introduce is greater than 9 and smaller than 2 but I dont know. Can you help me please?

```
(defun zecb (number base)
  (write-to-string number :base base))
```

Comment: Please give us some code you already have/tried.

Answer (score 5):

```
CL-USER 99 > (defun test (n)
               (check-type n (integer 2 9))
               n)
TEST

CL-USER 100 > (test 2)
2

CL-USER 101 > (test 9)
9

CL-USER 102 > (test 10)

Error: The value 10 of N is not of type (INTEGER 2 9).
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the condition system that coredump already mentioned there's also an [`assert` macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_assert.htm) that is part of Common Lisp. Try the following in your REPL:

```
(defun divide (num denom)
  (assert (not (= 0 denom))
          (denom)
          "Attempted to divide ~a by zero, use a different denominator!" num)
  (/ num denom))

(divide 42 0)
```

[(Non-interactive example)](http://ideone.com/wgVQ6m)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "report error"? If you mean something like throwing an exception in another languages, `error` may sute your needs:

```
(error "Base must be between 2 and 9")
```

Read more about [common lisp conditions and handlers](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html), if you need something more sufisticated than simple-error.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is printing an error, you can use one of the write/print function available (see [Output to character streams](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node198.html#SECTION002631000000000000000)).

Example:

```
(defun zecb (nb base) 
  "Test"
  (if (or (< nb 2) (> nb 9))
      (princ "Number Not in range")
      (* nb base)))
```

Comment: Most of common lisp'site relation operations, like < and > can take more than two arguments.  You can avoid the 'or' and just say '(not (<= 2 nb 9))' which looks much more like the mathematical notation.

Comment: Thanks. However, in math the operators not and <= are unary and binary ones, respectively. What does exactly mean ( <= a b c)? a <= b <= c?

Comment: Yes. <=is binary, but since it's also transitive, writing (<= a b c d ...) instead of (and (<= a b) (<= b c) ...) is nice, and it's easier to see the range.  E.g., when we'd write 0 <= i  <= n, it's nice to be able to write (<= 0 i n), since the left to right match the increasing order.  Even in languages with binary <=,is nice to write (0 <= i) && (i  <= n). Keeping the order consistent helps readers.

Comment: I see. Yeah, a nice shortcut. Just a minor quibble, strictly speaking that is no transitivity at play.

Comment: knowing that a < b and b < c implies a < c (transitivity) means that (< x1 ... xn) can be implemented with O(n) comparisons instead of O(n*n) comparisons (since the call  makes sure that each xi is less that each xj  (where i < j). The transitivity lets us have a more efficient implementation.

Comment: FWIW here are the docs on these functions: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm